# Replace multiple lines of file in Shell with variable

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, scripting

I have a txt file with:

```
A
B
<anything>
C
D
```

I want to replace from B to C in the file with a string, but this is not matching:

```
sed -i -e "s/B.*C/replace/g" $fileName
```

I have found how to target the multi-line string with:

```
awk '/B/,/C/' $fileName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '/B/{print "Replacement Text"} /B/,/C/{next} 1' "$fileName" 
A
Replacement Text
D
```

Explanation of `awk` code:

- `/B/{print "Replacement Text"}`

  When we see the `B` line, print out the new text, whatever it is.
- `/B/,/C/{next}`

  Any any line between `B` and `C` inclusive, skip the rest of the commands and jump to the next line.
- `1`

  This is `awk` shorthand for print the current line.

#### Variable text

If the replacement text is in the shell variable `newtext`, then use:

```
awk -v new="$newtext" '/B/{print new} /B/,/C/{next} 1'
```

#### To modify the file in place

If you have GNU `awk` v4.1.0 or better:

```
$ awk -i inplace '/B/{print "Replacement Text"} /B/,/C/{next} 1' "$fileName"
```

With earlier versions:

```
awk '/B/{print "Replacement Text"} /B/,/C/{next} 1' "$filename" >tmp && mv tmp "$filename"
```

Comment: I'm trying to modify the text file not just print

Comment: what if replacement text is a variable?

Comment: @user2827214 Assuming the replacement text is in a shell variable, see updated answer.  If not, let me know the source of the replacement text.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/B/,/C/c\replacement' file
```

or:

```
var=replacement; sed '/B/,/C/c\'$var file
```